# passar variavel javascript para php e gravar no banco de dados

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Preciso pegar as variáveis do alert e passar para PHP, e depois gravar no banco, a gravação do banco e tranquila, o que não to conseguindo e enviar para pagina teste

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>
setInterval("localizarUsuario()", 3000);
 
function localizarUsuario(){
  if (window.navigator && window.navigator.geolocation) {
   var geolocation = window.navigator.geolocation;
   geolocation.getCurrentPosition(sucesso, erro);
  } else {
     alert('Geolocalização não suportada em seu navegador.')
  }
  function sucesso(posicao){
    console.log(posicao);
    var latitude = posicao.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = posicao.coords.longitude; 
  
   
    alert(latitude + ' - ' + longitude )
   // $.get( "teste.php?latitude="+latitude+"&longitude"+longitude );
   
  }
  function erro(error){
    console.log(error)
  }
 
 
}
  
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use o ajax para isso:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>
setInterval("localizarUsuario()", 3000);
 
function localizarUsuario(){
  if (window.navigator && window.navigator.geolocation) {
   var geolocation = window.navigator.geolocation;
   geolocation.getCurrentPosition(sucesso, erro);
  } else {
     alert('Geolocalização não suportada em seu navegador.')
  }
  function sucesso(posicao){
    console.log(posicao);
    var latitude = posicao.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = posicao.coords.longitude; 
  
   alert('Aqui iremos começar nossa requisição ajax');
    alert(latitude + ' - ' + longitude )
   
    //ajax aqui
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "url_do_arquivo_que_quero_enviar_os_valores.php",
            data: { latitude = latitude, longitude = longitude },
            success: function (retorno) {
                console.log('Deu certo');
            },
            error: function(data) {
               console.log('Deu erro');
            }
        });
   
   
  }
  function erro(error){
    console.log(error)
  }
 
 
}
  
</script>
```

**o que é ajax?**

O [Ajax](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3585/ajax-basico-introducao.aspx#ixzz56FaMhckV) (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML) é uma tecnologia muito utilizada atualmente e que está em bastante evidência porque ela torna seus aplicativos muito mais dinâmicos e com maiores capacidades de respostas.

Já que está utilizando jQuery Ajax seria a melhor solução:

```
        //ajax aqui
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "url_do_arquivo_que_quero_enviar_os_valores.php",
            data: { latitude = latitude, longitude = longitude },
            success: function (retorno) {
                console.log('Deu certo');
            },
            error: function(data) {
               console.log('Deu erro');
            }
        });
```

`url` será qual arquivo vai ser chamado
`type` é o tipo da requisição, `get` ou `post`
`data` é as variaveis do javascript que voce enviara pro php
`success` é o que vai ser executado caso de sucesso na requisição 
e `fail` é o que vai ser executado caso a requisição falhe

**O que faço na página do PHP?**

```
$latitude = (isset($_POST['latitude '])) ? $_POST['latitude '] : "";
 $longitude = (isset($_POST['longitude '])) ? $_POST['longitude '] : "";
```

> assim ele vai preencher as variáveis caso elas tiverem setadas via
>   post

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo, adaptei para o que eu precisava aqui