# Como criar um botão pegar para pegar o valor selecionado em um form-control no PHP

Tags: php, button, combobox, dropdown

Tenho um form-control que carrega um Dropdown. 
O que eu preciso é de um botão em frente a este dropdown que ao selecionar um item do dele, clicar no botão, o valor selecionado do dropdown seja armazenado em alguma variável. Ou alguma maneira de ao selecionar um valor no dropdown este valor seja armazenado em uma variável automático e ao mudar o item selecionado no dropdown o valor da variável mude também.

Por exemplo, na imagem abaixo temos o meu dropdown.

[image]

Se olharmo no HTML deste dropdown, temos isso aqui

```
<select class="form-control" id="colaborador" name="colaborador">
<option value="">-</option>
<option value="117">117-GABRIELA</option>
<option value="144">144-GUILHERME</option>
<option value="12">12-KATHIA</option>                                                            
</select>
```

O que eu necessito é que ao selecionar, por exemplo, "114-Guilherme", e clicar no botão "Carregar" o value dele seja armazenado em uma variável, ou seja, a variável deverá receber 144.

Esse é meu código em PHP que carrega o dropdown (caso alguém necessite)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 form-inline">
        <select class="form-control" id="colaborador" name="colaborador">
            <?php
                if($_GET['COLSEL'] == ""){
                    echo '<option value="">-</option>';
                }
                $RetornoColaborador = retornaColaboradorGestor(intval($_SESSION['emp']), intval($_SESSION['cad']));
                foreach($RetornoColaborador as $key => $value){
                    if($value['numcad'] == $_GET['COLSEL']){
                        echo "<option value=".$value['numcad']." selected>".$value['numcad'].'-'.$value['nomfun']."</option>";
                } else {
                    echo "<option value=".$value['numcad'].">".$value['numcad'].'-'.$value['nomfun']."</option>";
                    }
                }                                                                   
            ?>                                                            
        </select>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-carregar">Carregar</button>                                                        
        <br/>
    </div>                                            
</div>
```

desde já eu agradeço.

Comment: Já tentou usar o jquery + javascript?

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [passar variavel javascript para php e gravar no banco de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/274372/passar-variavel-javascript-para-php-e-gravar-no-banco-de-dados)

Answer (score 0):

Dá pra resolver com JavaScript:

1. Declare a variável;
2. Adicione um evento de click no botão;
3. Ao clicar no botão, recupere o `select` via `getElementById`
4. Guarde o valor do `select` na variável

```js
var colaborador;
document.getElementById('btn-carregar').addEventListener('click', function(){
  colaborador = document.getElementById('colaborador').value;
  alert('colaborador é: '+colaborador);
});
```

```html
    <select class="form-control" id="colaborador" name="colaborador">
    <option value="">-</option>
    <option value="117">117-GABRIELA</option>
    <option value="144">144-GUILHERME</option>
    <option value="12">12-KATHIA</option>                                                        
    </select>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-carregar">Carregar</button>
```